# Show progress bar only in one of two fragments on tablet in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have two fragments in tablet: one left, one right.

I want now show a progress bar dialog only in left fragment. While progress bar is shown in left fragment user should be able to enter data in right side fragment.

When I use progress bar dialog (extends DialogFragment) then the whole activity is influenced and the user is not able to enter data in right side fragment.

How can I focus progress bar dialog only on left side fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using **ProgressBar** instead of ProgressDialog,since ProgressDialog is shown based on the parent Activity of the Fragments ,not any specific Fragment.